# Preg_split only once, disregard whatever comes after

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function getComponentFromFullName( $component_name )
{
    $regex_result = preg_split( '/-\d_/', $component_name, 3 );

    return $regex_result;
}
```

And my goal is to extract `post` from a string such as `demo-3_post`. Now, the problem is that if someone comes with `demo-3_post_post`, it'll give back `post_post`. I'd only like it to return `post`.

---

In: `getComponentFromFullName( 'demo-3_post_post' );`

Desired Out: `string: 'post'`

Comment: `preg_match()` may be the droid you're looking for.. but not 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` to return only the text before _ in the component name.

Like so:

```
function getComponentFromFullName($component_name)
{
    $split = preg_split('/-\d_/', $component_name);

    return preg_match('/_/', $split[1]) ? substr($split[1], 0, strpos($split[1], '_')) : $split[1];
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?